# Android Tab name is disappearing when swiping

Tags: android

I started a new project on Android Studio using Tabbed Activity. I did not change any code but what I observed is, when you swipe between the tabs then the name of the current active tab is not showing. I want the name to be shown up always. How can I do this?

I post the default code which is delivered automatically by Android Studio. I think the method `getPageTitle` is responsible for this.

```
import android.content.Context;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.annotation.StringRes;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

import com.example.customerservice.R;

/**
 * A [FragmentPagerAdapter] that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    @StringRes
    private static final int[] TAB_TITLES = new int[]{R.string.tab_text_1, R.string.tab_text_2, R.string.tab_text_3};
    private final Context mContext;

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mContext.getResources().getString(TAB_TITLES[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 2 total pages.
        return 3;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some screen shots

Comment: Please consider adding a minimum reproducible example .. the shared code doesn't provide any clue, even trying `Tabbed Activity` doesn't reproduce it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a new project

choose "Tabbed Activity"
[image]

open "SectionsPagerAdapter" Java class:

[image]

[image]

Click on "Tab 1" and "Tab 2"
[image]

you can see that the names of Tabs are stored in String resources
you can find it here:

[image]

then you can change it for example:
Hello Tab 1
Hello Tab 2
[image]

This is the result:

[image]
[image]

Edited:

If you want to see all the tabs names at the same time, you can use "ViewPager2", read this documentation:

[Create swipe views with tabs using ViewPager2](http://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-swipe-view-2)

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: , yes this is the problem. Why don't you see "hello tab 1" when tab 1 is active ? This is my problem. You don't see the tab name of the tab you are swiping to. So your answer does not solve my problem, but confirms it.

Comment: Why I can see it and you can't? If you do the same steps, you should get the same result as I got. can you please add some screenshots?

Comment: Sorry but I think you did not get me. If your check your last second picture you are on tab 1. You see only the "hello tab 2", the name of the first tab is not shown. Can you follow me now?

Comment: ah ok, you want to see all the tabs names at the same time, you can use "ViewPager2", read this: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-swipe-view-2

Comment: glad to help
I edited my answer
if you find it helpful can you please mark it as a useful answer?